# What would Earth look like if its rotation was inverted?

Tags: earth-like

Let's say we are in a parallel universe: we have an exact copy of our solar system, galaxy and so on.

The only difference is Earth: it rotates on its axes the other way around (to be more clear, in this universe it always rotated this way, it didn't suddenly change direction).

Would this have any effect on it (climate, geography, life and so on), or does the direction of its rotation not matter (other than inverting the position of sunset and sunrise)?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, for argument's sake let's assume the Moon's orbit is also reversed.

Comment: There are definitely climate differences on this planet. Certain weather phenomenon are not reversible... winds coming off an ocean and hitting mountains immediately tend to drop all their moisture immediately as rain, leaving none for the other side. If prevailing winds are the other direction, they come across those plains, hit the mountains, and over the other side move across the ocean. So rainfall patterns would be wildly different. Deserts would be in different locations and so forth.

Comment: Can we assume that the moon's orbit is also in the opposite direction? Otherwise you'll run into all sorts of issues with the Earth's rotation being braked.

Comment: @Rottweileronmarket-day. I hadn't even considered that. For the sake of the argument let's assume it is.

Comment: This question appears to fall under either the [What-If?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3033/6986) or [high-concept](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/6986) category of questions, neither of which is supported by this site. A glaring red flag is this part: "Would this have any effect on it (climate, geography, life and so on)." This question _needs more focus_ to bring it in line with site expectations.

Comment: @Frostfyre I don't think this falls under those categories, since I'm not seeking for someone's opinion but rather for facts about what would be impacted by it.
Also I believe this is exactly what the earth-like category is for: "describing a planet that follows the rules of Earth with exceptions outlined in the question. Usually questions [...] will be about the differences and the impacts of those differences".
Since I don't know what could be impacted, I need a global view of the effects. The answers already show what I mean: I wouldn't have thought about half of that stuff.

Comment: You want the continents to be the same? I'm not sure they would, since the swirling magma under the crust would be spinning the other way. There's cultural ramifications for reversing the setting and rising sun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Changes in Global Wind Patterns Disrupt Evolution as We Know It

This is what wind patterns look like now:
[image: Coriolis effect on wind patterns]

If the Earth reversed its spin, every one of those arrows <strike>reverses</strike> flips along the vertical axis.  This would cause drastic changes to the climate EVERYWHERE!  As John mentions above, if the prevailing winds change direction, then the locations of deserts, forests, and other biomes change completely as well.

Even if evolution continued on the same track, the development of human society as we know it would be completely different.

One concrete example I can think of is that this new world's equivalent of Columbus would likely have landed on mainland North America because he wouldn't have had to come down to the NE Trade Winds to cross the Atlantic.

### What about geological drift?

That's right, the direction the earth spins affects continental drift too.  Over billions of years, these subtle changes would make it so that the continents would not even be remotely recognizable.

You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwWWuttntio) to see how much continental drift we're talking about over 3 billion years, and now imagine that all the continents start out moving the opposite directions (probably not exactly how it works, but to give you an idea) and try to predict what the layout looks like after they bounce around for 3 billion years.

Comment: "That's right, the direction the earth spins affects continental drift too." - source?

Comment: Do you really mean that the arrows reverse, or do you mean they flip left-right (or east-west)? Cos I'm fairly certain that the situation will be the latter one, which will result in somewhat less dramatic changes than the former.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, You're correct; it flips left-right.  I'll make an edit.

Comment: @KeithMorrison The Coriolis effect works on magma currents that are responsible for some of continental drift.  [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270393934_Coriolis_effect_as_cause_of_East-West_Earth's_asymmetry) is an article talking about how they are responsible for Earth's East-West asymmetry.  It follows that tectonic drift is influenced non-trivially by the spin of the Earth.

Comment: @SirTain, that a hypothesis by *one* scientist that isn't not generally accepted by geoscientists.

Answer (score 4):

### Different length of day

The **solar day** is about 4 minutes longer than the **stellar day** because the Earth's rotation has to catch up with the apparent motion of the Sun in the sky.  If the Earth rotated the other way, the clock needs to be reset to midnight at 23:52 each day (until somebody "fixes" it).

### Different length of month

You've also flipped the Moon's orbit, so now the Moon goes around the Earth every 27.32 days (sidereal month) as always, but the Sun is running *backward* to greet the new Moon each month, so instead of about 29.5 days (it varies by the orbit) you have 25.something days in a lunar = synodic month.  (if you want decimals I ought to think more!)

Shorter days mean less variation in temperature and tide, though of course the day has lengthened substantially over geologic time anyway.  Shorter months might reduce the effect of extreme high "spring tides".  The mating cycles of sponges, which release gametes at a certain type of month, would be a little different, as would the feeding habits of countless animals that make use of the moonlight.

You could fix all that by reversing the orbit of the Earth around the Sun, but it's more complicated to figure out whether other planets would have affected it over time, the likelihood of asteroid impacts and so on.  And how far back would you go?  Earth couldn't have formed going the wrong way as planetesimals during the formation of the Solar system.

Answer (score -6):

Imagine instead of viewing the Earth from far above the North Pole, you view it from far above the South pole. That is the difference (assuming *all* rotations are reversed) if they are not it might complicate matters considerably.

If all rotations are reversed it makes no effective difference to anything.

Comment: Oh it makes *a lot* of difference to many things. Ocean currents will be vastly different. Winds will be vastly different. The trade winds will blow in the opposite direction. Etc. etc.

Comment: Worst of all, we couldn't make fun of Australia for being upside down.

Comment: I was assuming that all rotations were reversed. My mistake.